# Django регистрация и авторизация через функции

Tags: django, авторизация, регистрация

Не могу найти решение задачи.

На сайте нужна регистрация пользователя в дополнительными полями. И авторизация через email.
Поля я добавил через дополнительную модель:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  phone = models.IntegerField('Телефон', null=True, blank=True)
  country = models.CharField('Страна', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField('Город', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
  adress = models.CharField('Улица и дом', max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
  zip_code = models.IntegerField('Почтовый индекс', null=True, blank=True)
  birth_day = models.DateField('День рождения', null=True, blank=True)
  avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to='avatar', null=True, blank=True)
  agreement = models.BooleanField('Согласие на обработку', default=True)
  comment = models.TextField('Комментарии', max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)

  @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

  @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

  def admin_display(self):
    return self.user.last_name + ' ' + self.user.first_name
```

Далее сделал 2 формы для отображения в шаблоне:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    exclude = ('comment', 'register_date', 'avatar', 'password', )
    widgets = {
      'phone': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '9XXXXXXXXX', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'phone'}),
      'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Россия', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'country'}),
      'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Москва', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'city'}),
      'adress': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ленина 25', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'adress'}),
      'zip_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '101000', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'zip_code'}),
      'agreement': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input', 'id': 'flexSwitchCheckChecked'}),
      'birth_day': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'birth_day'}),
    }


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',)
    widgets = {
      'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Иван', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'first_name'}),
      'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Петров', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'last_name'}),
      'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ivan_petrov@email.ru', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'email'}),
      'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'password'}),
    }
```

Вот что в view:

```
def registration(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.username = request.POST['email']
      instance.set_password(request.POST['password'])
      instance.save()
      return redirect('registration')
    else:
      form = UserForm(request.POST)
      profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
      context = {
        'form': form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
      }
    return render(request, 'user_registration.html', context)
  else:
    form = UserForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    context = {
      'form': form,
      'profile_form': profile_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'user_registration.html', context)
```

Я не вывожу поле username. Вместо этого добавляю туда email.
Пользователь создаётся. Только пароль почему-то не зашифрован.
И залогиниться этот пользователь не может. Получаю ошибку соответствия логина\пароля.
И не могу найти пример функции логина.
Прошу помочь с этим.

Comment: Перед сохранением пользователя, сделайте `user.set_password(<пароль>)`

Comment: Или после сохранения, установите пароль указанным выше способом и сохраните объект

Comment: Получил ошибки:
для формы UserForm:
    username - Обязательное поле.
    date_joined - Обязательное поле.
для ProfileForm, user - Обязательное поле.

Comment: я не экстрасенс, я не вижу что вы изменили. Могу только сказать что 99%  что вы что то сделали не так.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос view. Там и добавил строку с преобразованием пароля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед сохранением пользователя, сделайте `user.set_password(<пароль>)`

Далее, по ошибкам:

```
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.username = request.POST['email']
```

Уже неправильно, `instance.username = request.POST['email']`. В форму поступает некорректное имя (поле `username` пусто). Поэтому и возникает ошибка. Как и остальные поля.

Можете в `clean` формы сделать `cleaded_data['username'] = cleacned_data['email']`

---

UPD:

Если кратко, то Вам нужно создать модель от `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` по аналогии с `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, убрав все лишнее, и указать полученную модель как модель для пользователей в `setttings.py` (`AUTH_USER_MODEL`).

В вашем случае, новая модель будет выглядеть так

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username = None
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

В этом случае, для указания связи на пользователя в `ForeignKey` и `ManyToMany` и `OneToOneField` лучше использовать `get_user_model()`, а и вообще лучше использовать эту функцию, а не указания конкретного класса.

---

Больше информации найдете по запросу `custom user model django` в поисковике, ниже ссылка с примером

[Пример](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

Comment: Не получается. Я просто не понимаю как работает обработка информации после нажатия кнопки "Зарегистрировать". А найти объяснений не могу. По факту, мне просто не нужно поле username. Но как от него избавиться я не знаю. Как привязать регистрацию и авторизацию к другой модели, не к User. Во всех мануалах стандартная схема. User и встроенные классы. И ничего найти другого не могу. Пытался обмануть, подсунув username, но тоже не получается.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение, а ещё больше за ссылку. В ссылке оказалась ещё ссылка и там такая цепочка, прям вкусно )
PS: добавь в профиле инфу для благодарности.
PSS: Может у тебя ещё есть ссылка на инфу, по созданию авторизации не привязанной к модели Users? Наверняка же есть разные способы, не только хранение метки "авторизован" в кэше. И опять же, интересно как это должно быть правильно. Хотя я уже наглею, попробую сам найти )

Comment: Не привязан к модели User - `get_user_model()` и `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Пожалуйста)